# Android Orientation and screen size issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know if the device screen width is larger than height
like HTC chacha that its screen's width is 480 and the height is 320

I used this code to determine it

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        if(display.getWidth() > display.getHeight())
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        else
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

the device actual screen size is 480w x 320h 
when I use this code I got 320w x 480h

Comment: I am confused... You state that the resolution is 480w by 320h and then you are asking if 320 is the height. What exactly are you looking to figure out?

Comment: the device actual size 480w x 320h
when I use this code I got 320w x 480h

Comment: Ok, I think you accidentally put height when you meant width in your last sentence then. Anywho it is possible that on this specific device they did it that way and when you hold the phone normally it actually things it is in landscape mode instead of portrait. Try running an activity that forces the orientation to portrait and see if it ends up getting shown sideways, if it does then you can be sure that this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will return width (w) & height (h) of screen.

```
DisplayMetrics dMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dMetrics);
float density = dMetrics.density;
int w = Math.round(dMetrics.widthPixels / density);
int h = Math.round(dMetrics.heightPixels / density);
```

activity is instance of Activity which would you like to get screen size.

You have to remember that: When your device is in landscape orientation, w > h. When it in portrait orientation w < h.

So from width & height you can detect your device is in what orientation.

Answer (score 4):

```
DisplayMetrics dimension= new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dimension);
        int w = dimension.widthPixels;
        int h = dimension.heightPixels;

      if(h>w){
        //"portrait"
      }
      else{
       //"landscape"
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

The orientation defines which side is width or height. If you got 480x320 it's because when you call `display.getWidth()` you're already in landscape mode. I don't know this device but it's likely that the default orientation is landscape when you hold it in portrait...

If you really need to know when you're in presence of such a device you could check the current orientation:

```
 getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

and compare it with the result with an [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) which uses the sensors to compute the real physical orientation in degrees.